# IE 11 Failure with PuTTY-Based SOCKS5 Proxy

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer, putty, internet-explorer-11, socks-proxy

I have set up a PuTTY-based SOCKS5 proxy as follows:

[image]

I have configured IE11 to use this proxy as follows:

[image]

I have also configured Firefox 52.7.3 (32-bit) to use this proxy in the exact same manner:

[image]

The content of proxyConfig.pac is as follows:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
  if ((url.indexOf(".mydomain.local") >= 1) ) {
    return "SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1080";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

I can reach Internet sites with either IE or Firefox.

I can reach intranet sites that are *not* under mydomain.local with either IE or Firefox.

I can reach intranet sites that *are* under mydomain.local with Firefox.

But here's the problem: I *cannot* reach intranet sites that are under mydomain.local with IE. Using **host.mydomain.local** as an example, I get this error:

[image]

**host.mydomain.local** does **not** resolve to an IP address on the near side of the proxy, either via the local hosts file or via DNS. However, it **does** resolve to an IP address, via DNS, on the far side of the proxy.

A packet capture shows that IE11 tries to resolve host.mydomain.local directly (i.e. on the near side of the proxy), rather than letting the proxy server do it. Firefox works because it does not attempt to resolve the hostname on the local side. It lets the proxy server do it.

If I edit my local hosts file such that **host.mydomain.local** will resolve on the near side of the proxy to what it would resolve to on the far side of the proxy, I still get failure. Although, the failure takes much longer. I believe this is because the failure to connect is now occurring because a response is not received (for which there could be a couple of causes) after some timeout rather than because of a name resolution failure (which occurs very quickly).

Is there any way I can force IE11 to **not** attempt to resolve the hostname and just allow the proxy server to do it instead?

If not, is there any other way around this problem?

### UPDATE 1

I'd forgotten that I'd hit this problem before and learned that IE11 does not implement SOCKS5 server-side name resolution. With this in mind...

Why does IE fail to connect when I put the IP address of **host.mydomain.local** in my local hosts file?

The IP address in question doesn't route anywhere on the local side. But still, shouldn't IE be passing the HTTP request to this IP address on to the proxy (where the IP address in question does route somewhere)?

### UPDATE 2

A packet capture shows that IE never even gets to the point of making the HTTP request. The initial TCP SYN is sent directly to the target IP address (which, as I said, routes nowhere on the local side); it does not attempt to send this TCP connection request through the proxy.

### UPDATE 3

I tried configuring the browser to use the proxy in a different way:

[image]

So now, everything goes through the proxy, not just requests to **mydomain.local**.

Having done this, I can now reach hosts on **mydomain.local**, but firewall restrictions prevent me from reaching intranet sites (via the proxy) not under **mydomain.local** or Internet sites.

Of course, these firewall restrictions are not IE's fault.

But it does show the trouble one may run into when attempting to use IE with a SOCKS5 proxy.

It seems there may be no good solution to this if one really wants to use IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best that can be done is to use SSH local port forwarding rather than to use a SOCKS5 proxy.

Here is my local hosts file:

```
127.24.0.1   host1.mydomain.local
127.24.0.2   host2.mydomain.local
127.24.0.3   host3.mydomain.local
```

Here's how I set up the local port forwarding:

[image]

Note that due to the necessity of re-using port 80 (every host I want to reach is serving HTTP on port 80), a different localhost IP address needs to be used for every destination host. Windows supports this.

My recollection is that Linux does not support using multiple localhost IP addresses. If I remember correctly, Linux changes any localhost address (i.e. anything in 127.0.0.0/8) to 127.0.0.1. Therefore, as soon as the SSH client attempts to create the second port forwarding listener, an error is encountered because of an attempt to re-bind port 80 to the same IP address (namely, 127.0.0.1).